# Disallowed Tag Present in AMP Wordpress (<comments></comments>)

Tags: comments, customization

We have a Wordpress blogging website with AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) Enabled into it. We are getting this error on Webmaster that the site (AMP Version) is not crawlable. It states that there is disallowed tag present; the  tag; however, in spite of disabling comments in AMP Panel; it still shows this tag.

Is there a way to remove this tag from using the functions.php file?

Here is the link of AMP version for reference. https://catking.in/dynastic-politics-india/amp/

Disallowed tag present.
[image]

Comment: The issue was a conflict with the Facebook Comments Plugin, have disabled that plugin but would definitely need a solution since we need the Facebook comments plugin.

Comment: you need to get in touch with the developers of that plugin.